# Does membase support tranactions?

Tags: transactions, couchbase, membase

I have a multi threaded evn. And I have to put/update two keys or not to update any keys. Does Membase supports it ? Is there any strategy I can follow ?

Answer (score 0):

While there is not strict transaction support on Couchbase, there is an operation called GETL which can help with these kinds of scenarios.  Have a look at the description in the [Couchbase Server 2.0 manual](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-architecture-apis-memcached-protocol-additions.html#couchbase-architecture-apis-memcached-protocol-additions-getl-usecases).